# Numbers in an interval C++

Tags: c++, vector, graphics

So I would like to make some numbers in the interval from -3 to 3 in order to plot these functions below, so i would like as many as possible numbers.

I am doing this:

```
double k[601];
double y[601];

for (int i = 0; i <= 600; ++i)
    {
            k[i]=cosh(i/100-3);
            y[i]=sinh(i/100-3);
    }
```

The problem arises when I plot these points. I always get the same 7 dots. I expected like 601 so my graph would be fuller.

For example:

```
 double k[11];
 double y[11];

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; ++i)
        {
                k[i]=cosh(i-5);
                y[i]=sinh(i-5);
        }
```

would plot me 11 points. I just don't get it -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i/100` does division of integers (and so `50/100` result in `0`), use floatint point: `i / 100.` (note the `.` after `100`).

Answer (score 2):

Because i is int, i/100 is a int too. Then from i = 0 to 99 you will get the same value of i/100.

Force i from int to double shall do it

```
    double k[601];
    double y[601];

    for (int i = 0; i <= 600; ++i)
    {
        k[i]=cosh((double)i/100-3);
        y[i]=sinh((double)i/100-3);
    }
```